# Why can't I download anything from the internet?

Tags: downloads

Every time I get to downloads and it finished, I click open file and archive manager pops up and says that an error occurred while opening files.

Questions:

1. What is archive manager?
2. How can I fix archive manager?
3. Can I replace archive manager?
4. Why doesn't auto run show up?
5. Does archive manager have anything to do with auto run?

Comment: Can you provide some more information about your particular problem. What are some of the things that you were trying to download? What version of Ubuntu is this and what browser are you using? Any any other relevant contextual information would be helpful in figuring out your problem.

Comment: sounds more as if archive manager is attempting to open what you downloaded. Archive manager is a graphical front end to the various archives in linux (zip, tar, etc). What are you downloading ? Try the command line : `ls` `ls ~/Downloads` and opening your download with an appropriate application.

Comment: go to ubuntu software center & type " tar " init install it all will be fine ....& it will be very helpful if u give us with screen shots and tell us which type of archive u r downloading

Comment: Can you provide the file extension of your file. Command "ls ~/Downloads". I am guessing that, you are downloading a unsupported archive format. Like rar which very popular in windows does not have default support in Ubuntu and for it you need to install unrar to open it. So give us the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Archive Manager](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/File%20Roller) is Ubuntu's default application for handling [archive files](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Glossary#archive).
2. Best not to 'fix' it, it's probably working just fine.
3. You can replace it with something like 7-Zip from the Software Center, though this is unnecessary.
4. Auto Run can't do anything with an archived or compressed file, you have to extract the archive first. Depending on the file type, you likely already have a default program to handle whatever it is. You can check this in System Settings / System Info / Default Applications.
5. Auto Run and Archive Manager are different things, as explained above.

You can open your Downloads list anytime from Firefox by typing <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd>. If you are having difficulty opening extracted files, make sure you have the [codecs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codec) already installed, try the [Ubuntu Restricted Extras](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats) from the Software Center.

Try downloading the files and opening them from a different browser, like Chromium. If that works, you have to reset your preferences in Firefox.